# StackOverFlow - Exception? I can't found the reason :-(

Tags: object, stream

I'm going to write a programm that can save a name and a birthday-date. After closing the programm the data shouldn't be lost. If you open the programm, you are able to add an additional user to the according users. Unfortunately I'm always get a stackoverflow - exception and i didn't found the mistake.

```
 <pre> package geburtstagstool;

import java.io.*;

public class GeburtstagsTool
{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        Eintrag eintrag = new Eintrag ("Miller","000000"); 
    }
}

class Eintrag implements Serializable
{
    Eintrag [] eintrag = new Eintrag [50];
    public String name;
    public String gebDatum;
    int i=0;

    public Eintrag (String name, String gebDatum)
    {
        eintrag[i] = new Eintrag (name,gebDatum);
        ++i;
    }         

    public void testSchreiben () throws Exception
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new      FileOutputStream ("eintrag.dat"));
        oos.writeObject(eintrag);
        oos.close();
    }

    public static Eintrag testLesen() throws IOException,     ClassNotFoundException
    {
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new     FileInputStream ("eintrag.dat"));
        Eintrag eint = (Eintrag) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return eint; 
    }
}
<code>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully working solution. This should get you started. Good luck.

GeburtstagsTool class:

```
public class GeburtstagsTool {

List<Eintrag> eintragList;

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    GeburtstagsTool geburtstagsTool = new GeburtstagsTool();
    geburtstagsTool.loadEintrag();

    System.out.println("What's already in the list: \n" + geburtstagsTool.eintragList);

    Eintrag eintrag = new Eintrag("Peyton Manning", "03/24/1976");

    geburtstagsTool.eintragList.add(eintrag);
    geburtstagsTool.writeEintrag();

}

public void loadEintrag() {}
{
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try
    {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("eintrag.dat"));
        eintragList = (List<Eintrag>) ois.readObject();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
        eintragList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeEintrag() throws IOException
{
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try
    {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("eintrag.dat"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    oos.writeObject(eintragList);
    oos.close();
}
```

Eintrag class:

```
public class Eintrag implements Serializable{

String name;
String gebDatum;

public Eintrag(String name, String gebDatum) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gebDatum = gebDatum;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Eintrag{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", gebDatum='" + gebDatum + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
 public Eintrag (String name, String gebDatum)
    {
        eintrag[i] = new Eintrag (name,gebDatum);
        ++i;
    }
```

It's an endless loop. It's a recursive call without ending.
You call the constructor that call's it self.. so it does that until the whole stack is full.. and then You get the SF exception :)

Comment: Think man, think :) I'm all Your for xxx$/hour if You want me to do the programming :)  What You need is a List<Eintrag> where You would store instances of them. So maybe 2 classes would solve this better ?